# PostgreSQL function to do calculation and then populate a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I’m looking for some help with a process I am trying to do in pgAdmin 4. I have a table called ‘sales’.
The attributes are;
saleId (primary key), saleUnitprice (INT), saleQuantity (INT), saleTotal (INT), saleDate (DATE), prId (foreign key to products table), spId (foreign key to salesperson table)

I have a second table called ‘saletally’ which I am looking to populate with the total sales per month per salesperson.

The SQL to get the totals is

```
SELECT spid, 
       SUM(saletotal) 
FROM public."sales" 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) = EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date) 
GROUP BY spid;
```

This return a number of records for each salesperson and their total sales for that month. I am trying to figure out how to put that info in a ‘saletally’ table.

I am looking to end up with

```
 stID   stTotal   spID    stMonth  
------ --------- ------ ---------- 
 st1        800   sp1    January   
 st2        900   sp2    January   
 st3        900   sp3    January   
 st4        950   sp1    February  
 st5        800   sp2    February  
 st6        950   sp3    February
```

I’ve not done anything this complicated in SQL before and I think I need to do it as a function in PostgreSQL. Based on the syntax for a function here is what I’ve managed so far;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalSales ()
RETURNS integer AS $totalsales$
declare
stId_var varchar(4) := stId +1,
stTotal_var := SELECT SUM(saletotal) FROM public."sales" WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) = EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date),
spId_var := SELECT spID FROM public.”sales”,
stMonth_var = EXRACT(MONTH from current_date);

BEGIN
Insert INTO public.”salestally”(stId, stTotal, spId, stMonth)
VALUES (stId_var, stTotal_var, spId_var, stMonth_var)
   RETURN totalsales;
END;
$totalsales$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think there needs to be a loop in there somewhere. I’d be grateful if someone could help with this or can point me in the direction of a good tutorial. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No function needed. If your SELECT statement returns the result you want to insert, you can use that directly as the source for the INSERT statement:

To get an incrementing column with your result, you can use the `row_number()` function. I would not store the `st` prefix - if that should be applied for all rows, it's simply a waste of space. You can easily concat that later in a view or in the select statement that you use to retrieve from the tally table:

```
insert INTO salestally(stId, stTotal, spId, stMonth)
SELECT row_number() over (order by extract(month from saledate)),
       SUM(saletotal), 
       spid, 
       extract(month from saledate)
FROM public.sales
GROUP BY spid, extract(month from saledate);
```

I would also not store the month as a name, but as a number. That way you can format latter when you display the month.